# Fabric UI: How do I position a ContextualMenu?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, office-addins

I want to be able to open a ContextMenu at a specified point.

I can see from the API docs (https://dev.office.com/fabric#/components/contextualmenu) that I have to set `targetPoint` to an `IPoint`, but there is no explanation of how to actually do this.

So- how do you use `IPoint` to position components in Fabric UI?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(**EDIT MARCH 2019:** some users are reporting that `target` should be used instead of `targetPoint` in the example below. That said the example below worked for me.)

OK- this API is as far as I can see completely undocumented, but the following will generate a contextual menu around a mouse click

```
class Preview extends React.Component {
  constructor (props) {
    super(props)
    this.showContextMenu = this.showContextMenu.bind(this)
    this.state = { showContextMenu: false }
  }
  showContextMenu (e, text) {
    this.setState({
      showContextMenu: ((text.length > 0) ? true : false),
      selectionText: text,
      targetPoint: {
        x: e.clientX,
        y: e.clientY
      }
    })
  }
  render () {
    return (
      <div className='ms-font-m ms-bgColor-themeLighter' onMouseUp={(e) => this.showContextMenu(e, window.getSelection().toString())}>
        <div>
          { this.state.showContextMenu && <ContextualMenu useTargetPoint="true" target={this.state.target} items={[ { key: '1', name: "boo" }, { key: '2', name: "yah" }]} /> }
        </div>
        <p>
          This is a really interesting paragraph, etc...
        </p>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

For now (office-ui-fabric-react 6.92.0), there is no `useTargetPoint` and `targetPoint` props anymore.

We should use `target` which type is 
`Element | string | MouseEvent | IPoint | null`

```js
    <ContextualMenu
  target={{x: 200, y: 200}}
  items={[ { key: '1', name: "boo" }, { key: '2', name: "yah" }]} />
```